# Mapping Insensitive case - Code First - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, code-first

I have a project with C# where I use Code First EF with SQL Server.

My problem is that I have multiple instances of my database. In one of them, I have the column name "**Hello**" and in the other "**hello**" for example.

How do I manage case sensitivity in such as scenario?

Comment: Are you using different contexts for each instance?

Comment: No one Context. I'm sorry i have another problem. The column is missing in SQL Server. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework don't care about **case sensitivity** of your columns or tables names.

You can use the same `DbContext` on the two database as long as the tables and columns names match (case sensitivity is ignored).